# In Java, Why ResultSet does not allow you to run next() more than 1 time?

Tags: java, database, resultset

Look at this code:

```
ResultSet results=preparedStmt.executeQuery();

while (results.next()){
   String subject=results.getString(1);
   System.out.println(subject +" 1st time");
}

while (results.next()){
   String subject=results.getString(1);             
   System.out.println(subject+ " 2nd time");
}
```

Why the system only prints out the result at the 1st time, & does not print out result in the second time?

If we want to run results.next() more than 1 time, then what is a proper way to code?

Comment: Just glancing at the fine manual.. [`ResultSet.first()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#first%28%29)?

Comment: Because you reached the end of the results.  `ResultSet`'s (way back in the day) were single direction traversable (there where less drivers that supported bi-directional cursors then those with).

Comment: @Andrew: almost good. It's the other one. From the 2nd paragraph of the javadoc: *"Initially the cursor is positioned **before** the first row. "*. There's a `beforeFirst()` method which does exactly that. The canonical approach, however, is to map the result set to a collection of beans, close everything off as soon as possible and then postprocess that collection instead.

Comment: Thax u BalusC, 
results.beforeFirst(); is right way to code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while( rs.next() )` will advance the 'current row' cursor to the end of the set.

By default, a `ResultSet` is read-only and forward only, so once you get to the end, you'll need to call first() to start over. Note: `first()` is an optional method and may not be supported by your driver.

Answer (score 3):

You are not running .next() one time. A single while loop will run it multiple times until you reach the end of the result set.  When the second while loop is reached, there is nothing left in the result set to go over: you are at the end of it.  you'll have to run the query again to start over or generate a [scrollable resultset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html):

> ```
>        Statement stmt = con.createStatement(
>                                       ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
>                                       ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
>        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a, b FROM TABLE2");
>        // rs will be scrollable, will not show changes made by others,
>        // and will be updatable
> ```

and call `rs.first()`